# What characters does the standard tokenizer delimit on?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, delimiter

I was wondering which characters are used to delimit a string for elastic search's standard tokenizer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) I believe this is the list of symbols/characters used for defining tokens: http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Word_Boundaries